# move one element to another element's offset position using jquery

Tags: jquery

I struggling with move one label into next of another animated(left:200px) label's position.Actually i am developing game like match the following like below image,

[image]

when I click on left side questions it will animate left side for 200px and same time click on right side answers, if it is right answer that right side clicked label should move near next to left side clicked label's place. I tried code below,

**CSS :**

```
.questions {

margin: 5px;
padding: 10px!important;
border: 2px dashed #f0ad4e;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
z-index: 50;
float: left;
text-align: center;

list-style:none;
}
.answers {

margin: 5px;
padding: 10px!important;
border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
z-index: 9999;
float: left;
text-align: center;
list-style:none;
}

#first {

    float:left; /* add this */

    height: 350px;
    padding-left: 350px;
}
#second {

   float:left;
     height: 350px;
     padding-left: 450px;
}

label, span { position: relative; }
```

**index.jsp :**

```
<div id="first" class="">            

<%

    String class1=session.getAttribute("class").toString();
    //String userid=session.getAttribute("user_id").toString();
    String chapter="Plants";
    String subject=session.getAttribute("subject").toString();


    try{

    if(session.getAttribute("class")!=null&&session.getAttribute("user_id")!=null&&session.getAttribute("subject")!=null)
        {

           System.out.println(class1+"\n"+subject);

           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");
            Statement st=connection.createStatement();
            Statement st2=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2=null;
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select questions from tbl_MatchTheFollwing where class='"+class1+"' and subject='"+subject+"' and chapter='"+chapter+"' order by rand() limit 5");


     while(rs.next())
       {    
         String qest=rs.getString("questions").toString();

         String nospacestring = qest.replaceAll("\\s+","");

         System.out.println("nospace strinf :"+nospacestring);

          %>
       <label id="<%=nospacestring %>" class="dropzone"><%=qest %></label><br><br><br><br>


       <% }%>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
      <%

       rs2=st.executeQuery("select answers from tbl_MatchTheFollwing where class='"+class1+"' and subject='"+subject+"' and chapter='"+chapter+"' order by rand() limit 5");

       while(rs2.next())
           {
             String answer=rs2.getString("answers");

             String [] a2 = answer.split("_");
             System.out.println("a[0] :"+a2[0]);
             System.out.println("a[0] :"+a2[1]);


            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 1; i < a2.length; i++) {
             result.append( a2[i] );
            }
            String mynewstring = result.toString();

            System.out.println("mynewstring :"+mynewstring); 

            String labelname = mynewstring.replaceAll("\\s+","");

            System.out.println("labelname  :"+labelname); 

            StringBuffer result2 = new StringBuffer();
               for (int i = 0; i == 0; i++) {
                result2.append( a2[i] );
               }
              String mynewstring2 = result2.toString();

              System.out.println("mynewstring2 :"+mynewstring2); 

              String idnamenospace = mynewstring2.replaceAll("\\s+","");

              System.out.println("labelname2  :"+idnamenospace); 


               %>
    <label id="<%=idnamenospace %>" class="item" name="<%=labelname%>"><%=a2[1] %></label><br><br><br><br>


             <% }%>
           </div>


         <%


            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
           {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

        %>

<input type="hidden" id="textid" value="">

<script>
$('.questions').click(function(){

$(this).animate({left:"200px"},"slow" );

var Ques = $(this).attr('id');

$('#textid').val(Ques);

});

$('.answers').click(function(){

$(this).animate({right:'200px'});

var Ans =$(this).attr('id');//get id value of clicked right side answer

var Ques =$('#textid').val();//get id value of clicked question

if(Ques==Ans)
    {
      T  = $("#"+Ques).offset().top;//getting current top of cliked question
      L = $("#"+Ques).offset().left;//getting current left of cliked question  
      // alert('x :'+T+'\n'+'y :'+L);

      $(this).animate({bottom:T+'px'}); // here trying to move near right question but cant!
      $(this).animate({right:L+'px'});

   }
});
</script>
```

I want to do like below image,

[image]

Comment: suggest you create a demo with enough css in it to replicate problem. WIthout seeing your html/css and not knowing what isn't working it is hard to help

Comment: @charlietfl check now my question.

Comment: On first glance: `$("#textid").val()` will [give you a value](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not an id. The question as it stands is quite difficult to read. You might want to check out [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: doesn't really help having server code to replicate client side problems especially when the html shown doesn't have any of the classes that are used in the script. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: the element need to be in position relative or absolute top be deplaced with top/left/right/bottom

Comment: @ekans check now.animation happening fine but i want to move one elemnt to near another element